# MVC4: DateTime column sorting in asp.net mvc webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, webgrid

I have been trying to **sort** `DateTime` column in `asp.net mvc webgrid`.

Here is my code:

```
 grid.Column(header: "Product Purchased Date",columnName:"PurchasedDate" canSort: true,format: @<text>
        @item.PurchasedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")</text>
```

when i tried using above code i am getting this errors:

> cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to
>   'System.Func'

The best overloaded method match for `System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments`.

if i apply the above code without using columName i am unable to perform sorting.

Apologize if i missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that, if you want to sort it as a string, add a function within your Model object that returns the value as a string instead of converting it inline.  So there would be a field such as PurchasedDateAsString on the object.

For instance this is something I used in a recent project.  The field `DateRange` is returned as a string and can be sorted upon just like it was a "base" field:

```
public class PeriodView
{
    [Key]
    public int PeriodId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }

    public string DateRange
    {
        get
        {
            var start = String.Format("{1}-{0}",
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(StartDate.Month).Substring(0, 3),
                StartDate.Day);

            var end = String.Format("{1}-{0}",
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(EndDate.Month).Substring(0, 3),
                EndDate.Day);

            return String.Format("{0} to {1}", start, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hai Shane thanks for your reply.Is there any change to perform sorting without doing it in model object.?

Comment: Shane your code returing as '01-JAN'. But i need in this format '01/08/2014'.

Comment: Correct.  You can return any value of course with String.Format().  I think you want to have a display and sort version however.  Your display version using the format 01/08/2014 but the sort version being 2014-01-08 (year-month-day) so you don't get the wrap around effect.

Comment: Is there any solution for this.? 
Because i have to display Date in the **UI**  in this format '01/08/2014'

Comment: Yes you specify two fields, sort on one, but display the other.

Comment: Could you provide solution to do this in UI for sorting after converting it from 2014-01-08?

Answer (score 0):

If you convert DateTime to string and format it, the WebGrid will sort the column as a string, which is not correct for DateTime Format Column expected result.